# catkin permission

Tags: ros, permissions, catkin-workspace

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I installed ROS as a root, and now I am getting this error when I try to run catking_init_workspace:

```
Could neither symlink nor copy file "/opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/toplevel.cmake" to "/home/user/worspace/src/CMakeLists.txt":
- [Errno 13] Permission denied
- [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/user/worspace/src/CMakeLists.txt'
```

How can I get rid of this issue?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/185763/catkin-permission/) by [Pototo](https://answers.ros.org/users/11046/pototo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 803 on 2014-07-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is generally not a good idea to install ROS as root... Even when built from source, a home directory is usually used. Because you installed as root, you have a problem here with permissions... Unless you want to `sudo !!` for the rest of your time using ROS, I'd say it's a good time to reinstall...

regards,

-Hunter A.

---

Originally posted by [allenh1](https://answers.ros.org/users/1086/allenh1/) with karma: 3055 on 2014-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-07-09**:
A reinstall is not necessary, but you should consider removing the whole directory tree or chown -R user /home/user/workspace and or rm -rf /home/user/workspace and any other place you have root owned files in your user directory.